# Antonym(s) of pleonasm

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Specifically words like succinct and concise.

While not exactly the antonym of pleonasm, I would especially like to find a word that implies someone who speaks just enough, perhaps due to wisdom. The opposite of impulsive, excessive speech?

Comment: Are you looking for a noun to describe that _person_? Or just words like succinct or concise that describe the speech? If the latter, I'd suggest _pith(y)_.

Comment: Perhaps a *prudent speaker*

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Do you know of a noun that describes a pithy person?

Comment: Did you try a thesaurus? They wil give antonyms as well as synonyms. How about 'laconic' or 'succinct'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps an *incisive* speaker; that being clear and direct.
Or a *direct* speaker; as an adjective for coming straight from a source (e.g. the shortest distance).